# I need a way to automatically download a file after payment is authorized

Tags: javascript, html

Hi my website sells serum presets packaged in zip files and i need a way to have it automatically download after the payment (using paypal api)authorizes.
I have it so that it creates an  tag element with the download but thats not efficient because if a user accidently reloads the page they would have to buy it again so i need it to download automatically here's what i have right now.

```
onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
    return actions.payment.execute().then(function(payment) {
        var divArea = document.getElementById("theDownload");
        var download = document.createElement("a");
        download.setAttribute('href', "soundPacks/evil.zip", "", "");
        download.innerHTML = "evilSerumPresets.zip<br>";
    });
}
```

Comment: _"I have it so that it creates an tag element with the download but thats not efficient because if a user accidently reloads the page they would have to buy it again"_ How could the user accidentally reload the document if clicking a button makes purchase and prompts user to download file?

Comment: ok the paypal purchase button brings up a window were you can log in to your paypal or pay with credit or debit. Its not going to automatically download anything. all it does is creates an anchor tag(which is the download)in the div area that i made. so if a user accidentally reloads the page for whatever reason , that anchor tag would no longer exist until another payment is made

Comment: My question is instead of creating an anchor tag for the user to click on and download, i want the download to trigger automatically once the purchase is authorized, i am asking how i would do that in javascript.

Comment: When the payment is completed the user is redirected to a completed transaction page, yes? Provide the download button at that page. Another solution would be to simply email the file to the user. You can use  `window.open()` with `Content-Type` set to `"application/octet-stream"` to offer file for download.

Comment: Alternatively call `.click()` on the `<a>` element with `download` attribute set

Comment: okay i see what your saying. That makes sense . thanks